# How do I connect to Facebook chat using Username/Password auth option and successfully send a message in either Javascript or Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, facebook-chat, node-xmpp

I have tried using the `node-xmpp` package and `blather` gem. I got the furthest with blather, but succeeded with neither.

Blather attempt:

https://github.com/adhearsion/blather/issues/119

Node-xmpp attempt:

https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp/issues/149

Answer (score 1):

From the Facebook API Docs:

> **Authenticating with Username/Password**
>
> The DIGEST-MD5 SASL mechanism is available to support traditional XMPP
>   or multi-protocol IM clients that are not customized for (or even
>   aware of) Facebook. This mechanism requires prompting the user for his
>   or her password; therefore, it should only be used when necessary. In
>   particular, it **MUST NOT** be used for any client that:
>
> - Proxies the XMPP connection (the connection must be directly from the user's computer to Facebook).
> - Reports messages or any other information about user activity to a third party (including the client developer).
> - Integrates with Facebook, or has a Facebook Application ID. If your application does any of the above, you must use Facebook Platform authentication instead.

I think your application is doing one of the following, correct me if I'm wrong but based on the links you provided for your blather and node-xmpp issues I think you may be trying to violate the third criteria.

> - Integrates with Facebook, or has a Facebook Application ID. If your application does any of the above, you must use Facebook Platform authentication instead.

Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: I only created a Facebook app ID in order to try that auth method because username/password wasn't working. I have no desire for Facebook Platform integration, and would prefer to get it working with just username/password.